# Shopping cart "loop" issue after upgrading to 1.9.3.6

Tags: cart, upgrade, magento1.9.3

I just upgraded from Magento 1.9.3.2 to **1.9.3.6** with the connect manager, now there is an issue with the Shopping cart.
After entering the customer address and clicking the "Next" button, it redirects back to the shopping cart view. So it's impossible to complete an order.

Also, "system.log" and "exception.log" show nothing particular beside a small PHP notice.

Is there a way to fix/debug this ?

EDIT: "formkey" field is not missing

Comment: Sounds like your custom address form is missing the formkey probably made obligatory by one of the security patches included in the update.

Comment: I did inspect the form element and the "formkey" field is there.. What else could be causing this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide a URL showing the issue?

Comment: The server responds with an internal error, so you're likely to find the php line causing it inside the apache error log. If you don't have access to the log, my best bet for a starting point is to search for the custom `saveBillingAction()` method in charge – don't forget to include app/code/local/Mage in your search – and step through its code to see where the request stops.

Comment: Looks like you resolved the issue? Was it caused by the configuration cache?

Comment: I found the solution: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Re-SUPEE-9767-v2-causes-saveBilling-500-server-error/td-p/71939

Comment: Great! You may add the solution as an answer so others will find it useful, too. … Crosspost, sry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Re-SUPEE-9767-v2-causes-saveBilling-500-server-error/td-p/71939

Delete the old unused Action.php file

Comment: Only delete the file if you know what you're doing, i. e. you don't need any part of the overriding class, otherwise incorporate missing methods into it.